# Recursive function of range (from range-v3) causes compilation to diverge: why?

Tags: c++, recursion, range-v3

For some reason, the code in the listing below causes clang++ and g++ to use 100% CPU, and fill up memory until my system hangs.

**Please note**, this is a toy example for a talk. I'm aware that `accumulate` and `transform` are the standard way to do this, but this code is an intermediate point in a chain of reasoning.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

template <typename F, typename R, typename T>
T rec_map_sum(F f, R r, T tally) {
  if (ranges::begin(r) == ranges::end(r))
    return tally;
  else {
    auto r_head = *ranges::begin(r);
    auto r_tail = r | view::drop(1);
    return rec_map_sum(f, r_tail, tally + f(r_head));

    // this also crashes:
    // return rec_map_sum(f, r[{1, end}], tally + f(r_head));
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << rec_map_sum([](int x) { return x * x; }, view::iota(0, 10), 0)
            << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The `rec_map_sum` function is meant to implement a recursion that takes a range of integers and a unary function, applies the function element-wise to the range, and produces the sum of the mapped elements.

I have two questions: (1) what is the cause of the divergent behaviour, and (2) how should I make and pass down the tail view so that the compilation doesn't crash?

Comment: How do you handle end of recursion ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh my, I got so hung up on the fact that I made the compiler crash, I forgot to write the conditional return. I'll amend it. Thanks a lot for pointing out my gaffe quickly.

Comment: Your second branch still force instantiation of infinite number of function `rec_map_sum`.

Comment: You should have `if constexpr (ranges::begin(r) == ranges::end(r))` (which is not possible) to have given code to compile.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're obviously correct, but forgive me: I'm not sure why, unless the size of the range is somehow part of the signature. From my (obviously flawed) understanding, in `main()`, I should be instantiating `int rec_map_sum(std::function<int(int)>, some_range_type, int)`, and the return statement should fit the same signature.

Comment: `r` and `r | view::drop(1)` and `r | view::drop(1) | view::drop(1)` are 3 different types. Which each generate its own `rec_map_sum`.

Comment: @Jarod42 RE `r` vs `r | view::drop(1)`—Oh... man. Now I see why you suggested `if constexpr`. The recursion is getting sorted out at compile time. That's not what I wanted. Do you know of any way for me to construct a range from the tail that doesn't change the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pointed out by Jarod42, but the solution is pretty simple. You need a **type-erased view** that can take any range. Luckily, [such a thing exists](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1any__view.html). Change your code to:

```
template <typename F, typename R, typename T>
T rec_map_sum(F f, R r, T tally) {
  auto r2 = any_view<T>{r};
  if (ranges::begin(r2) == ranges::end(r2))
    return tally;
  else {
    auto r_head = *ranges::begin(r2);
    auto r_tail = r2 | view::drop(1);
    return rec_map_sum(f, r_tail, tally + f(r_head));
  }
}
```

This prints 285.